# How to avoid hyphenations in important paragraphs like Funding Statements in a double-column format document (IEEE papers)?

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation

For a new paper I am writing to IEEE journals (double-column formats), many important paragraphs suffer from the default hyphenation in LaTeX. Especially, I don't like the hyphenations given in the Funding Statement at the end of the paper. If I don't want hyphenations in some words such as "under", "Programme", "Excellence", "Operational" etc., how do I instruct LaTeX not to hyphenate these words in the IEEE LaTeX document? Thank you..

Comment: You haven't specified some very important aspects of your document's design. E.g., do you want the lines to be fully justified, or would you prefer them to be typeset ragged-right, aka un-justified?

Comment: \sloppy (inside a group) will not prevent hyphenation, but it will reduce them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question, I checked some online resources and found the advice: Add the command

```
 \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

in the preambles. I tested, and it works beautifully. I plan to use this simple command in future papers, as I like to avoid hyphenation in my papers.. Thanks!

Comment: If you happy with your answer, you can accept it (end inform the site readers, that your problem si solved.

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question as the question asks how to adjust the hyphenation in specific paragraphs, but that disables hyphenation for the entire document.

Comment: typesetting double columns with no hyphenation is likely to make a lot of ugly white space, why would you suppress hyphenation?

Comment: It would help if you clarified what you mean by "it works beautifully". Did you maybe simply want to say that "it succeeds in suppressing all hyphenation"? Well, that would be exactly what the package is *supposed to* do, isn't it?

Comment: When I write research papers using Microsoft Word, I choose an option "don't hyphenate" (single or double column) and I am happy with its outputs. I was getting annoyed seeing hyphenated paragraphs throughout the paper when I type using LaTeX. I agree with friends that we may see white spaces, but by rewriting the document (after seeing the LaTeX output), we can make adjustment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't want hyphenations in some words such as "under", "Programme", "Excellence", "Operational" etc., how do I instruct LaTeX not to hyphenate these words in the IEEE LaTeX document?

If those are the only four words which shouldn't be hyphenated in your document, I can see no downside to issuing the instruction

```
\hyphenation{under programme excellence operational}
```

in the preamble. (If you employ the `babel` package, then the `\hyphenation` instruction should occur *after* `babel` is loaded.)

I can't help but add the following remarks. For documents that employ European languages -- I'm afraid I don't really know much about typography involving non-European languages -- I must confess to not understanding some persons' apparent all-powerful aversion to hyphenation. (You're definitely not the only one who appears to have a strong dislike of hyphenation...) Medieval scribes employed hyphenation for many centuries prior to the invention of movable type, and [Johannes Gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Gutenberg) definitely employed hyphenation to its full advantage for the famous [42-line bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutenberg_Bible), which was printed shortly after 1450. For sure, suppressing *all* hyphenation in documents that feature fairly narrow columns is very likely to create more typographic problems -- such as very loose inter-word spacing -- than it solves.